# PHP: User gives two numbers, if divisible echo green box, else red box

Tags: php, if-statement

How can I submit the two numbers properly with $_post?

Here is my code:

```
Geef twee getallen in:<br><br>
<form action="1GDM_IT2_EXAsem2_taheriHamza_vrg2_verwerking.php" method="post">
Getal 1: <input type="text" name="getal1" />
<input type="submit" name="getal1" />

<br></br>Geef nog een getal in:<br></br>
<form action="1GDM_IT2_EXAsem2_taheriHamza_vrg2_verwerking.php" method="post">
Getal 2: <input type="text" name="getal2" />
<input type="submit" name="getal2" />


</form>


<?php
```

The code that checks it:

```
if(($_POST['getal1'] % $_POST['getal2']==0))
{
    echo "Is deelbaar";
}

else {
    echo "Is niet deelbaar";
    }


?>
```

thanks for helping

Comment: Is there a problem with the code?  If so, what is it?

Comment: what did you try. do you know how to write properhtml forms ? and how php if statements work?

Comment: Why do you have 2 forms? And they are nested... You should use only 1 form with multiple `input`s and only one submit button. Also your element names shouldn't match. Use different names for the `input`s and a different name for the submit button.

Comment: Put both fields in the same form.

Comment: @jon that's the answer

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get any errors? What green/red box? This is woefully undetailed.

Comment: Looks like the OP is on an exam right now, am I right HamzaT? :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Put both text input fields into **one** form. (You can not nest forms, and you can only submit one form at a time.)
2. Name your submit button something else, **not** the same as the input field(s) - the way you are doing it now, the submit button value overwrites the input value from PHP's view.
3. One submit button is enough to submit the one form.

Answer (score 0):

You are usign two forms when you just need one. By the way, first form was not closed, and had second one nested. Anyway change to this

```
Geef twee getallen in:<br><br>
<form action="1GDM_IT2_EXAsem2_taheriHamza_vrg2_verwerking.php" method="post">
Getal 1: <input type="text" name="getal1" />

<br></br>Geef nog een getal in:<br></br>
Getal 2: <input type="text" name="getal2" />
<input type="submit" name="getal2" />
</form>
```

and just check with

```
if(isset($_POST['getal2'])
{
```

Now you just need to check for input fields you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="1GDM_IT2_EXAsem2_taheriHamza_vrg2_verwerking.php" method="post">
Getal 1: <input type="text" name="getal1" />
<input type="submit" name="getal1" />
<br></br>Geef nog een getal in:<br></br>
Getal 2: <input type="text" name="getal2" />
<input type="submit" name="submitbtn" />
</form>
```

Don't nest forms.
Don't use 2 submit buttons.
Don't name inputs the same as submits.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="1GDM_IT2_EXAsem2_taheriHamza_vrg2_verwerking.php" method="post">

 <input type="text" name="getal1" />
 <input type="text" name="getal2" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" />

</form>
```

Try this. hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you want:

```
<form action="1GDM_IT2_EXAsem2_taheriHamza_vrg2_verwerking.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="getal1" />
    <input type="text" name="getal2" />
    <input type="submit" />
 </form>
```

And the PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['getal1'], $_POST['getal2'])) {
  if((intval($_POST['getal1']) % intval($_POST['getal2']) == 0)) {
    echo "Is deelbaar";
  }

  else  {
    echo "Is niet deelbaar";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="1GDM_IT2_EXAsem2_taheriHamza_vrg2_verwerking.php" method="post">
Getal 1: <input type="text" name="getal1" />
<br /><br />
Getal 2: <input type="text" name="getal2" />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="getal" />
</form>
```

You should put both values in one form. And also try to avoid giving same name for multiple form elements.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<form action="1GDM_IT2_EXAsem2_taheriHamza_vrg2_verwerking.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="getal1" />
    <input type="text" name="getal2" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php 
if(($_POST['getal1'] % $_POST['getal2']==0))
{
    echo "<p BGCOLOR='GREEN'>Is deelbaar</p>";
}

else {
    echo "<p BGCOLOR='RED'>Is niet deelbaar</p>";
    }    
?>
```